# error 'Nonetype' object not callable even though callable() shows true

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "url"
html = requests.get(url)

stuff = bs(html.content, 'html5lib')

text = stuff.find(
    'p', 
    attrs={'class' : 'class'}
    )

print(callable(text))
cleaned = text.replace("n", '')
print(cleaned)
```

this is a simplified version.

the replace() isnt working on the variable text saying that nontype object is not callable. the callable() returns true so i dont understand why its saying its uncallable. the website doesnt use any anti-scraping measures as when i print(text) the output shows the html that i want. but when i try to remove the extra html and only get what is inside the p tag it shows the variable text where the html is stored is uncallable

Comment: That means `replace` is `None`, not `text`. `text` would be an element though, not a string like you appear to be expecting, since it came from `find`.

Comment: Instead of `callable(text)`, try printing `type(text)` and maybe `dir(text)`.  That'll show you the type of `text` and what methods are available on it.